# Jquery validate plugin number validation with special characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate plugin to validate a Number field in my form.

The script for validation is

```
NUMBER: {
    required: true,
        number: true,
    minlength: 4,
    },
```

which validates my formfield `<input name="NUMBER" type="text" id="NUMBER" value="" maxlength="4" >`

but, i want to include (or allow) special characters "`+`", "`-`", and "`,`", and word "`NA`" in my formfield. How can I make this possible?? The word "`NA`" should be validated when it is alone, without any other letter or number..

Thanks in advance.. :)

blasteralfred

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [your own custom rule for validator](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage):

```
$.validator.addMethod("custom_number", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value === "NA" ||
        value.match(/^[0-9,\+-]+$/);
}, "Please enter a valid number, or 'NA'");
```

This validates the field if it's optional, equal to "NA" or meets the regular expression.

And then you would just apply this new rule to whatever field you want:

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        number: {
            required: true,
            custom_number: true,
            minlength: 4
        }
    }
});
```

Obviously, you should replace the name `custom_number` with something a bit more descriptive.

Check out a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/RtK2p/1/

Answer (score 1):

Check this one http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jvalidation more flexible and easy to use with less than 3 k size.

in your case you can use default data-validate-format validator

```
<input data-validate-format='/^([0-9,\+-]{0,4}|NA)$/' />
```

Check regex I put as value of the attribute

They have a sample for extending with optional validations such as numbers

```
$.fn.validations.options.validators.age = function(){
  return this.val()>0&&this.val()<100;
}
```

and in your html you add sth like

```
<input data-validate-age='true' data-validate-error='.err1' />
<div class='err1'>Age should be more than 0 and less than 100!</div>
```

Check Full Documentation for [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://www.tectual.com.au/posts/14/jQuery-Validator-Plugin-Validation-Plugin-.html)